# Retrieve contents of a textbox in Infopath

Tags: infopath

i need a way to insert the contents of a textbox into an email when the user clicks the submit button. right now, i have a hidden section that emails certain fields when the users clicks the submit button, but the field contents show up as images in the emails. this leads to strange rendering on some mobile devices when the user tries to respond to the email.

UI instructions preferred, but I can try my hand at development if that's what we need to do. any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to add lots more information for this to be an answerable question.  If that sounds daunting, best to hire someone to ask the question here for you, or buy a book.  as the question stands now, it's not suitable for this site.  Read the FAQ to see examples of questions that don't meet the criteria (e.g. of basic understanding of programming).  Welcome to the site, I'm sure you'll have better luck given more learning.

Comment: How are you actually sending the form in the email? Are you just sending the current view?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this via workflow in SharePoint designer. Just add a workflow step that emails users and then retrieve the data from the form submission by clicking the add lookup to body button in the bottom left corner.  There are a number of ways you could get this set-up.  If you clarify your question, I will clarify my answer but hopefully this will be good enough to point you in the right direction.